# How to customize the appointment panel and bean in jfxtra agenda?

Tags: java, javafx-8, jfxtras

I want to create a custom appointment panel for a jfxtra agenda.

Exactly i want to display some specific text other than the time range already shown.

I also want to have a custom appointment bean, containing other information that can be shown in the panel.

(I really don't know where to start from )

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Agenda does not expose any display information, because it may have all kinds of different representations; the panels, or a list view, or... So you have to modify the skins. You should start at the AppointmentRegularBodyPane

https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/src/main/java/jfxtras/internal/scene/control/skin/agenda/base24hour/AppointmentRegularBodyPane.java

The skins you are looking at are constructed pretty straight forward; there is a day pane which contains the different appointment panes, etc.

Comment: thanks for the link. please remove the '|' character after the last '/' to work ;). i'am taking a look at it and try to understand.

Comment: Indeed. Where that pipe symbol came from... Anyhow, I removed it.